# How to express real matrices as linear combinations of unitaries?

Tags: vqe, linear-algebra

I am working on using Variational Quantum Linear Solver (VQLS) for some tasks. Here, we need to represent matrix A as a linear combination of unitaries.

$$ {\bf A} = \Sigma^n_{i=1} c_iA_i $$

My questions are:

1. Is there any general decomposition method of finding such $A_i$ unitaries? Please note that data is **real-valued** and not only binary.
2. Should matrix A be broken based on its basis? (Basis can be eigenbasis of the matrix `A` or it can be general basis like Pauli matrices)
3. How do we find the value of `n` i.e., the number of such unitaries?

Comment: Is $A$ a finite-dimensional matrix? There are $N^2$ linearly independent $N\times N$ unitary matrices, so that should help you.

Comment: Yes, A is a finite-dimensional matrix, most probably of the form $ 2^n * 2^n $

Comment: "*Should matrix A be broken based on its basis?*" I don't understand. Isn't this precisely what are you asking? That is, you are asking how to decompose $A$ with this basis?

Comment: No, I am asking to break this matrix in terms of unitary matrices, not necessarily based on basis of the matrix A. I want to know different techniques for performing this action. Also wouldn't breaking based on basis result in vectors rather than matrix?

Comment: asking "how to decompose $A$ in terms of a collection of unitaries $\{A_i\}$" to me reads the same as "how to break $A$ based on the unitaries $\{A_i\}$"

Comment: I think the confusion is in the phrase "the basis of $A$." To me this is not a well-defined idea: there are always lots of bases in which any matrix can be expressed. Perhaps you mean the eigenbasis of $A$? In that case, the eigenbasis of $A$ will have nothing (or very little...) to do with the expansion coefficients in the basis of unitary matrices.

Comment: @glS you're right that's what I have asked? But for the second question, I want to know, should this breaking up of matrices be done using its bases like eigenbasis or general basis of n-dimensional matrix like the Pauli matrices. Hope it clarifies now?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I've updated the question for this clarification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select a basis of unitary matrices with respect to which you can decompose your matrix. For example, if your matrix $A$ is $2^n\times 2^n$, then you can select the Pauli basis
$$
\sigma_y,\qquad y\in\{0,1,2,3\}^n
$$
You can find the decomposition very easily. Notice that if
$$
A=\sum_yA_y\sigma_y
$$
then calculating
$$
\text{Tr}(A\sigma_x)=A_x2^n
$$
because $A_x^2=I$ and the traces of all tensor products of Paulis except the all-identities tensor are 0.

Take, as an example, a matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
$$
Here, we have $n=2$, so we take the set of Pauli matrices
$$
\Lambda=\{I\otimes I,I\otimes X,I\otimes Y,I\otimes Z,X\otimes I,X\otimes X,X\otimes Y,X\otimes Z,Y\otimes I,Y\otimes Y,Y\otimes Z,Z\otimes I,Z\otimes X,Z\otimes Y,Z\otimes Z\}.
$$
For each in turn ($\sigma\in\Lambda$) you just calcuate $\text{Tr}(\sigma A)/4$. For instance,
$$
\text{Tr}(X\otimes X\cdot A)=2
$$
so $A_{1,1}=1/2$. Ultimately, you find out that
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}(X\otimes X-Y\otimes Y)+\frac14Z\otimes Z+\frac34I\otimes I+\frac{1}{4}(Z\otimes I-I\otimes Z)
$$

Of course, if you want to ask a question along the lines of the *smallest* set of unitaries with which you can decompose a specific $A$, that might be a very different question!

Comment: this paper (draft? writing? pdf?) by Wheeler is probably relevant here: https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Unitary%20Bases.pdf (sorry, don't know of other non-pdf sources)

Comment: I might be asking very trivial question here, sorry for that. But could you shed some light on how you get these $ A_y \sigma_y $. That's really the main point of asking this question. If you can show some example or post a link to where this is happening, it would be a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: You just find the full set of Pauli operators (there's $4^n$ of them) as the $\sigma_y$. You then find the $A_y$ as I specified - multiply your $A$ by $\sigma_y$ and take the trace.

Comment: Thanks! Explained beautifully!

Comment: And in case it helps, the only reason the coefficients $A_y$ are real is because the example matrix is Hermitian, not because the matrix elements of $A$ are real.

Comment: What if the coefficients come out unreal, does that mean that `A` is not Hermitian?

Comment: Yes. For this specific decomposition, if $A$ is hermitian, the coefficients are real. So, if they are complex, it must mean that $A$ is not Hermitian. So, even if $A$ is real, the decomposition can by complex.

Comment: @DaftWullie could you please have a look at this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21383/18425)  It's the next step, where I am again stuck in implementing VQLS

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer above, if anyone needs implementation to this question in Qiskit.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.circuit import library


def make_square(matrix):
    # Pad with 0 to make square matrix
    if matrix.shape[0] != matrix.shape[1]:
        if matrix.shape[0] > matrix.shape[1]:
            # Pad columns
            pad_width = [(0, 0), (0, matrix.shape[0] - matrix.shape[1])]
        else:
            # Pad rows
            pad_width = [(0, matrix.shape[1] - matrix.shape[0]), (0, 0)]
        matrix = np.pad(matrix, pad_width)    
    return matrix

def get_pauli_bases(dimension):
    pauli = {
        'x': Operator(library.XGate().to_matrix()),
        'y': Operator(library.YGate().to_matrix()),
        'z': Operator(library.ZGate().to_matrix()),
        'i': Operator(library.IGate().to_matrix())
    }

    bases = {}
    # Creates bases matrix in dimension mentioned in parameter
    # For dimension 1, bases = {I, X, Y, Z}
    # For dimension 2, bases = {II, IX, IY, IZ, XX, XY, XZ, YY, YZ, ZZ}
    if dimension == 1:
        return pauli
    else:
        for permutation in product(*[list(pauli.keys())]*dimension):
            permutation = "".join(permutation)
            bases[permutation] = pauli[permutation[0]]
            for idx in range(1, len(permutation)):
                bases[permutation] = bases[permutation].tensor(pauli[permutation[idx]])
        return bases

def linear_combination_pauli(matrix):
    matrix = make_square(matrix)
    matrix_len = matrix.shape[0]
    
    # Assuming matrix dimension is in power of 2
    nqubits = int(np.log2(matrix_len))
    
    bases = get_pauli_bases(nqubits)
    decomposition = {}
    for base, base_matrix in bases.items():
        decomposition[base] = np.trace(np.dot(base_matrix, matrix)) / matrix_len
        
    return decomposition, bases

def validate_decomposition(decompositon, bases, original):
    created = sum(coeff*matrix.data for coeff, matrix in zip(decomposition.values(), bases.values()))
    created = np.around(created, 3)
    return (created == original).all()
```